# how to convert videos to flv using ffmpeg in php?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

i am trying to convert some different video formats to flv using ffmpeg. But it seems that only some videos go through.

`ffmpeg -i /var/www/tmp/91640.avi -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv /var/www/videos/91640.flv`

here is some debug info:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 23.98 (65535/2733) -> 23.98 (5000000/208541)
Input #0, avi, from '/var/www/tmp/91640.avi':
  Duration: 00:01:12.82, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5022 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1280x528 [PAR 1:1 DAR 80:33], 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 448 kb/s
WARNING: The bitrate parameter is set too low. It takes bits/s as argument, not kbits/s
Output #0, flv, to '/var/www/videos/91640.flv':
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 1280x528 [PAR 1:1 DAR 80:33], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: adpcm_swf, 22050 Hz, 5.1, s16, 0 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening codec for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

also, if i try to grab one frame ad convert it to jpeg i get an error as well

`ffmpeg -i /var/www/tmp/91640.avi  -an -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y /var/www/videos/91640.jpg`

debug info

```
...
[mpeg4 @ 0x1d7d810]Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error occurred
Usually that means that input file is truncated and/or corrupted.
```

im thinking that the image fails because the video conversion failed in the first place, not sure though

any ideas what goes wrong?

Comment: You should always include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard , it does. The execution of ffmpeg commands are in php, even though i haven't post them in there.

Comment: I'm referring to the issue itself, not if you are or are not using PHP.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard you have a point, but your answer did fix my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bits, not kbits

From your console output:

> WARNING: The bitrate parameter is set too low. It takes bits/s as argument, not kbits/s

Use `32k`, not just `32`.

## Only stereo or mono is supported

The encoder `adpcm_swf` ony supports mono or stereo, so add `-ac 2` as an output option. The console output would have suggested this if you were using a [recent `ffmpeg` build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

## Use `-vframes 1` for single image outputs

Instead of `-t 00:00:01 -r 1` use `-vframes 1`.

## A better encoder

Instead of using the encoders `flv` and `adpcm_swf`, I recommend `libx264` and `libmp3lame`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -q:a 5 output.flv
```

- `-preset` – Controls the encoding speed to compression ratio. Use the slowest preset you have patience for: ultrafast,superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow.
- `-crf` – Constant Rate Factor. A lower value is a higher quality. Range is 0-51 for this encoder. 0 is lossless, 18 is roughly "visually lossless", 23 is default, and 51 is worst quality. Use the highest value that still gives an acceptable quality.
- `-q:a` – Audio quality for `libmp3lame`. Range is 0-9 for this encoder. A lower value is a higher quality.

### Also see

- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)
- [Encoding VBR (Variable Bit Rate) mp3 audio](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encoding%20VBR%20%28Variable%20Bit%20Rate%29%20mp3%20audio)